# Extract a single value from a dataframe/tibble the tidy/dplyr way?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I know a few ways to get a single value out of a dataframe/tibble.

```
library(dplyr)

start_date <- tibble::tribble(
  ~StaffAbbrev, ~starting_date,
  "Alexander", "2021-08-23",
  "Cornelis", "2021-08-23",
  "Sotirchos", "2021-08-23",
  "Zhao", "2021-08-23",
  "Park", "2022-02-14",
  "Sarkar", "2022-04-04"
)

#Tidyverse way
Alexander_start_v1 <- start_date %>%
  filter(StaffAbbrev == "Alexander") %>%
  select(starting_date) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  unname() 

#Base R way
Alexander_start_v2=start_date$starting_date[start_date$StaffAbbrev=="Alexander"]
```

Is shorthand/more elegant/one-liner tidyverse way to extract a single specific value out of a dataframe/tibble?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some possibilities:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
start_date %>% deframe %>% getElement("Alexander")
## [1] "2021-08-23"

library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
start_date %>% deframe %>% .[["Alexander"]]
## [1] "2021-08-23"

library(dplyr)
start_date %>% filter(StaffAbbrev == "Alexander") %>% pull
## [1] "2021-08-23"

library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
start_date %>% filter(StaffAbbrev == "Alexander") %$% starting_date
## [1] "2021-08-23"
```

and here is base R code

```
with(start_date, starting_date[match("Alexander", StaffAbbrev)])
## [1] "2021-08-23"
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answers helped me think of this one also start_date %>% deframe() %>% pluck("Alexander")

Comment: you can also do `pull %>% nth` if you need to extract one value from more than one value returned by filter. See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nth.html