# R How to get element of data frame based on corresponding value in row?

Tags: r

I have a data frame:

```
lookup_df <- data.frame(variable_name=c("x", "y", "z", "r"), function_name=c("table", "min", "table", "table"))


  variable_name function_name
1             x         table
2             y           min
3             z         table
4             r         table
```

I want to be able to get the corresponding function_name depending on a provided variable_name. This is what I have so far but its result is a list, what I want is the actual string value of the function_name

```
lookup_df %>% filter(variable_name == "x") %>% select("function_name")[function_name]
```

For example, given the variable_name "z", I should get "table" as a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`select` always returns a dataframe. The correct `dplyr` verb you should use is `pull`.

```
lookup_df %>% filter(variable_name == "x") %>% pull(function_name)
```

Output

```
[1] "table"
```

Answer (score 4):

I recently learned that there are many ways to do this

[Extract a single value from a dataframe/tibble the tidy/dplyr way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70533197/extract-a-single-value-from-a-dataframe-tibble-the-tidy-dplyr-way)

but here is the one i like best

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)

lookup_df %>% deframe() %>% pluck("z")
#> [1] "table"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

YOu can add `pluck` to the bottem line

```
> lookup_df %>%
+   filter(variable_name == "x") %>%
+   select(function_name) %>%
+   pluck(1)
[1] "table"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are couple of base R options -

```
#1. Using `==`
lookup_df$function_name[lookup_df$variable_name == 'z']
#[1] "table"

#2. Using `match`
lookup_df$function_name[match('z', lookup_df$variable_name)]
#[1] "table"
```